# My C++ code doesn't work well for larger, random arrays

Tags: c++

I have written the code to generate an array with the size of 1,000,000 and sort it with merge sort and insertion sort algorithms and then measure the time taken for each process. It works perfectly for array sizes up to 100,000. But once I change `n` (size of array) to 1,000,000 and compile and run it, the program working. I'm using Code::Blocks 13 compiler which has the g++ compiler that follows the c++11 ISO language standard.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
void insertion_sort(long inputSize, long  *inputArray);
void merge(long *inputArray, long low, long mid, long high);
void merge_sort(long *inputArray, long low, long high);
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    long n = 1000000;
    long inputArray1 [n];     //Declare the two arrays of size n
    long inputArray2 [n];
    cout << endl << "Unsorted List" << endl;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) //initialize the arrays of size n with random n numbers
    {
        inputArray1[i] = inputArray2[i] = rand(); //Generate a random number
        //cout<<inputArray1[i]<<" ";  //Display each element in the array
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point Start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    insertion_sort(n, inputArray1); //calling the insertion_sort to sort the array of size n
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point End =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long long timeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(End - Start).count();
    cout << endl << endl << "Sorted list using Insertion Sort" << endl;
    /*for (int x=0;x<n;x++){     //Display the sorted array which was sorted using insertion_sort
          cout<<inputArray1[x]<<" "<<" ";
    }*/
    cout << endl << "Time taken = " << timeTaken << " microseconds";
    Start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(inputArray2, 0, n); //calling merge_sort to sort the array of size n
    End  = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    timeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(End - Start).count();
    cout << endl << endl << "Sorted list using Merge Sort" << endl;
    /*for (int x=0;x<n;x++){     //Display the sorted array which was sorted using merge_sort
        cout<<inputArray2[x]<<" "<<" ";
     }*/
    cout << endl << "Time taken = " << timeTaken << " microseconds";
    return 0;
}

void insertion_sort(long inputSize, long *inputArray)
{
    for (long i = 1; i < inputSize; i++)
    {
        long key = inputArray[i];
        long b = i - 1;
        while ((b >= 0) && (inputArray[b] > key))
        {
            inputArray[b + 1] = inputArray[b];
            b = b - 1;
        }
        inputArray[b + 1] = key;

    }
    return;
}

void merge_sort(long *inputArray, long low, long high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        long mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge_sort(inputArray, low, mid);
        merge_sort(inputArray, mid + 1, high);
        merge(inputArray, low, mid, high);
    }
    return;
}

void merge(long *inputArray, long low, long mid, long high)
{
    long n1 = mid - low + 1;
    long n2 = high - mid;
    long *L = new long [n1 + 1];
    long *R = new long [n2 + 1];
    for (long i = 0; i <= n1; i++)
    {
        L[i] = inputArray[low + i];

    }
    for (long j = 0; j <= n2; j++)
    {
        R[j] = inputArray[mid + j + 1];
    }
    L[n1] = INT_MAX;
    R[n2] = INT_MAX;
    long i = 0;
    long j = 0;
    for (long k = low; k <= high; k++)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j] )
        {
            inputArray[k] = L[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            inputArray[k] = R[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }

    }
    delete[] L;
    delete[] R;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Looks like stack overflow. Use `std::vector` instead of native array.

Comment: Attach code, please.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the .exe file gets stopped working"? It crashes? Never finishes? etc

Comment: yes.It crashes I have attach the code

Comment: Or if you don't want to use a `std::vector` allocate the arrays with new and delete them at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long n=1000000;
long inputArray1 [n];    
long inputArray2 [n];
```

First, variable length arrays are not valid in standard C++, `n` should be `const`.

Assuming `long` is 4 bytes, these two arrays occupy 8MB of stack size, which is larger than the size of a normal stack. The program crashes because of [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables).

To fix the problem, use `std::vector` instead of native arrays.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But is there any other way other than using vectors? Because I'm not actually familiar with it.

Comment: @DushaniWellappili Yes, make it static.

Comment: variable length arrays **are valid** in standard C++ since c++11 or c++14 not sure now.

Comment: @Quest Thanks. Yes it is valid in c++11 also

Comment: @DushaniWellappili I haven't checked with C++14 yet, but definitely not C++11, some compiler supports it as extension.

Comment: @DushaniWellappili Making it static or global works, or use `new` like the other answer. However, I didn't mention `new` because it's easier to work with `std::vector`. If you are not familiar with it, then get familiar with it.

Comment: @YuHao ok.I'm not exactly sure. but it did worked for me. I used new and it works now. But when i give n as 1000 and run it several times, Insertion Sort time is high than the merge sort. But we know that merge sort has the less time complexity. Can you explain that please?

Answer (score 2):

You can create arrays on heap using new:

```
long* inputArray1 = new long[n];    
long* inputArray2 = new long[n];
```

Don't forget to delete it at end of main.

Comment: @DushaniWellappili - just curious, but insertion sort for 1 million longs seems like it would take quite a while, what kind of time did you get for this?

Comment: yes. It takes a lot of time. I got 1165.76 seconds. I didnt run the insertion sort for 10 million. Because it takes even more  lot of time.